# How can I set a value from an asynch DataSource Change Event?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've this piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onCompanyChange(e) {
        // here I need to manage ${Code}
    }
</script>

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Company)
    .Name("Company")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataValueField("Name")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetCompanies", "Companies");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(false);
    })
    .Events(e => e.Change("onCompanyChange"))
    .Template("<table><tr><td width='300px'>${Name}</td><td width='100px'>${Code}</td><td width='200px'>${State}</td></tr></table>")
    .OptionLabel(Resources.Resources.LblNotDefinedList)
    .Filter("contains")
)
```

I'd like to send to `onCompanyChange` the value of `${Code}`, which is retrieved (as json) after an asynch request to `GetCompanies`.

Once I've it, I'll set its value to a `MVC HiddenField`, and send back to the server.

How can I pass that value through the `Kendo` change event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle "select" event to get selected item. Something like that from kendo [documentation](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/events):

```
function onSelect(e) {
                if ("kendoConsole" in window) {
                    if (e.item) {
                        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
                        kendoConsole.log("event :: select (" + dataItem.text + " : " + dataItem.value + ")");
                    } else {
                        kendoConsole.log("event :: select");
                    }
                }
            };
```

But you can get some behavior only with "change" event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onCompanyChange(e) {
        // here I need to manage ${Code}
        var selectedIndex = this.select();
        if (selectedIndex != null){
           var selected = this.dataItem(selectedIndex);
           var code = selected.Code;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what's that `this.select();` and `this.dataItem();` within the function?

Comment: There are dropdownlist's functions, because "this" in events will be set to your dropdownlist. `select` returns the index of the selected item, if called with no parameters [doc](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/methods/select) and
`dataItem()` returns the data item at the specified index. [doc](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/methods/dataitem)

Comment: Sorry, i made small mistake in second code, now it fixed.

Comment: But I  simply call a function without passing any object. How can it retrieve it by `this`?

Comment: The event handler function (in your case it's "onCompanyChange") dynamically binds to dropdownlist widget, so you can access to dropdownlist widget instance in your handler by using "this". So, you don't need to call "onCompanyChange" by yourself, it will be fired when you will change value on dropdownlist.